# Is there any standard template or considered a suitable format for writing test documentation for a project?

Tags: reactjs, testing, django-rest-framework, documentation, documentation-generation

I am working on a Django-Rest-React project, and I need to create test documentation for my team. I generally know what test documentation should contain, like a checklist, test case, use case, bug report etc.
However, can anyone give me some tips on any additional items to include or arrange everything in the documentation to make it more readable?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone here can.

You are working in a team. Every team is different. Why do you expect we can help you when we don't know your team?

If you want to make your documentation better for *someone*, go ask that person. If you want to help your team by providing better documentation to *them*, go ask *them*, not random people on the Internet who don't know your context.

> I generally know what test documentation should contain, like a checklist, test case, use case, bug report etc.

First, I'd question the fact you need a documentation. Then I'd question every one of those things you mentioned. In my experience, no one really reads documentation, so if you share bugs in it, it's likely no one will read it and they will remain in the product. But that's my experience, maybe you have a different one, which is why you should go ask *your team*.